# Can't do a login with Spring and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm trying to create a login system with MySQL and spring, and I've been able to successfully register a user and enter that data into MySQL, but I've been unable to login a user, as I keep getting incorrect username/password error. My `@GetMapping` works for the login controller since the log.info keeps giving me this every time I reload the page:

> Logging in User(id=null, firstname=null, lastname=null, email=null, username=null, password=null)

But the @PostMapping refuses to work and I can't even log anything.

My Login controller

```
package com.example.candyshop;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.time.*; 
import java.util.*;
import lombok.*;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.*;
import java.security.Principal;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Data
        class Message{
            private String message;
            public Message(String m) {
                message = m;
            }
        }

        class ErrorMessage{
            private ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
            public void add(String m){
                messages.add(new Message(m));
            }
            public ArrayList<Message> getMessages(){
                return messages;
            }
            public void print(){
                for(Message msg:messages){
                    System.out.print(msg.message);
                }
            }
        }


    @GetMapping
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("login") User user, Model model) {
        log.info("Logging in " + user);
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        
        User oauthUser = userService.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());

        log.info("User " + oauthUser);
        if(Objects.nonNull(oauthUser)) {
            return "welcome";
        } else {
            return "login";
        }
    }
}
```

Login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Candy Shop Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/homepage.css" th:href="@{/css/homepage.css}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/styles.css" th:href="@{/css/styles.css}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "topnav">
        <img class="logo" src="../static/images/candyshoplogo.webp" th:src="@{/images/candyshoplogo.webp}">
    </div><br>

    <div>
        <a class="form-group" th:href="@{/homepage}">Candy Shop</a>
    </div>

    <div class="signup-form">

    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        Invalid username and password.
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
        You have been logged out.
    </div>
    
        <form action="/examples/actions/confirmation.php" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" method="post">
            <div class="form">
                <h2>Sign in</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" th:field="*{username}" required="required">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" th:field="*{password}" required="required">
            </div>        
            
            <div class="form">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign In</button>
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

UserService Class

```
package com.example.candyshop;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public User login(String username, String password) {
        User user = userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
        return user;
    }
}
```

User class

```
package com.example.candyshop;

import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

@Entity
@Table(name ="Users")
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private String firstname ;
    private String lastname ;
    private String email ;
    private String username ; 
    private String password ;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `@ModelAttribute` for logging in.
`@ModelAttribute` will take a query string. data is being passed to the server through the url.

you should you `@RequestBody` instead.

data will be pass to the server through a full JSON body.

basically, `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` work with different formats.

and for that reason you are getting `Null`.